# Stripe Node JS integration no error callback

Tags: node.js, parsing, stripe-payments

I've been trying to integrate Stripe with Node JS, but I can't get Stripe to return the error. I pass malformed data on purpose, but I still can not get the error back.

I'm new to Node JS.

Here is Stripe's official doc:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addCredit", (request) => {
// Use stripe API and your own 'secret key'
var stripe = require('stripe')('xdsewew');

// Charge user's card
stripe.charges.create({
    amount: request.params.amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    source: request.params.token,
    description: request.params.userId,
  }, function(error, charge) {
      return(error);
  });
```

});

Maybe I'm not doing it right when I try to return the error?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the same and I'm able to log the error

```
  var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7d");

    stripe.charges.create(
      {
        amount: 2000,
        currency: "usd",
        source: "tok_mastercard",
        description: "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
      },
      function (err, charge) {
        if (err) {
          // different ways to log error 
          console.log("error message -> ", err.message);
          console.log("error type - >", err.type);
          console.log("eror raw -> ", err.raw);
          return err;
        }
        console.log(charge);
      }
    );
```

[image]

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Probably it's an issue with Parse Server.